# Phrases indicating time in the future

Tags: phrase-requests, future

I was taught to use 未来 and 将来 to reference the future but after actually interacting with native speakers I've noticed that these words are not often used.

I'd like to know how to express the following future time phrases as I don't believe that they would use either 未来 or 将来. I'll give my best guess as to how I think that the sentence might be expressed.

I'll see you in a bit.（もうちょっとで会う）

In the future, I'd like you to email me instead of call me. (今後、電話じゃなくてメールをしてください)

No one knows what the future holds for us.(この先に何があるかが誰でもわかりません)

This was merely a proof of concept and future projects will be at a much larger scale. (これはただの概念実証(?)なので次のプロジェクトは遥かに大きな規模になります）

In addition are there any other useful/common time phrases for talking about the future?

Comment: "この先**に**何があるか**が**誰**で**もわかりません" -> 「この先何があるか**は**誰**に**もわかりません」の方が自然だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

I (can) see you in a bit.

> もうちょっとしてから会える。

I (will go) see you in a bit.

> もうちょっとしてから会いに行く。

This seems fine to me.

> 今後、電話じゃなくてメールをしてください

Note that

> 誰でも = anyone

and

> 誰も = no one

Using この先 is fine. (If you really wanted to use 将来 or 未来 here would probably have been the most suitable so far)

次のプロジェクト is also fine. You could also say 今度、今後、今から、etc

Comment: `もうちょっとしてから` -> So, you're saying もうちょっとで doesn't work here, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that もうちょっとで　is better/more natural than もうちょっとしてから

What about しばらくしてから会いに行く？But this is for longer term usage(maybe more than 1 week).

I would think that 未来 and 将来 are used to express things that would happen much further in the future(at least 10 years-ish?).